# import csv into Excel with #N/A

Tags: excel, csv

I have a application that is printing some numerical values to a .csv file and I would like to do the printing in such a way that the csv file can be opened with a double click in Excel without any custom import or replacing things etc. Once the file is opened, I mark two or three columnes and plot them as X,Y plot.

This works already nicely for numbers. If my application cannot print a number, it should instead print some string like "NA" or "#N/A" or whatever and Excel should import it as an "#N/A" so that it will be skipped in the plot but I can still see that something has been printed.

What string do I have to place in the csv file to have it imported as "#N/A" in Excel?

Comment: I am afraid there is no such value when opening CSV. Perhaps can you leave blanks in CSV and use SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) to change them into #N/A after opening ?

Comment: That would probably work, other workarounds are possible, like writing NA and then converting into #N/A or into =NA()

Answer (score -1):

I tried importing .csv files in which my app has written =NA() when no data were available and it worked just fine, Excel displays #N/A in the cells and =NA() in the text input window (or whatever it is called)